# Mocking data for extjs Direct calls

Tags: extjs4, ext-direct

I build my ExtJs app using ExtDirect call (stores, forms or any action). The problem is that in order to code well you need your direct calls functional, which is hard to do it fast.

Is there any way in having "direct calls" mocked up?

In this way the front end developer will write from the beginning in JavaScript the specs for backend responses. WIth only one flag in the app, the code wi ll know to make he righ calls to the server so the backend developer would be able to focus in writing backend responses having some functional JavaScript code.